# Azure Storage: Is there way to retrieve permission info from an SAS Url?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

In my func, I get an SAS token as an input. And I need to decide if the delete permission is granted from the token.

I tried to parse it like this way:

```
var permission = containerSasUrl.Split('&').Where(param => param.StartsWith("sp=")).ToArray(); 
if (!permission[0].Contains('d'))
{
    throw new StorageException(string.Format("Unable to delete files from {0}, check the storage permissions.", containerSasUrl));
}
```

But failed with the Url has the permission info embedded in access policies. Like:

https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/test?sr=c&sv=2014-02-14&**si=DownloadToolPolicy**&sig=NMczy2Dn9uktwIaP2qIxqLSnZteyOd%2FAffgawDLfV7g%3D

Any other route I can work on?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately No, at least for checking if `delete` permission is included in SAS. At first I thought that I could try to deleting a non-existent blob and catch the exception and if the SAS token does not have this permission I would get a `403` error however I got a `404` error in both scenarios i.e. when blob exists and does not exist and the SAS token does not have delete permission.

Comment: Correct, I tried this route before. And both get 404. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have to do a pilot download& delete to work around this issue.
Welcome to more elegant solutions.